# Intersection of 2 arrays even if misspelled

Tags: php, arrays, string-comparison

```
$a = array('apple', 'banana', 'orange'); //etc...
$b = array('papel', 'abanan', 'grape');  //etc...
```

The output should be `'apple', 'banana'`..... You need to use some of the built in array method.

In the second array note that the word 'apple' and 'banana' is spelled wrongly. The words 'papel', 'abanan' can also be like 'leppa', 'nnaab' or any other format, but it must contain all the alphabetic characters of the corresponding word.

Comment: what have you tries so far?

Comment: What if I mis-spelled `apple` as `bananaplep`?  What then?

Comment: @AbraCadaver -  `apple` cant be spelled as `bananaple` it should match the exact word only the order of alphabet changes, it can be in any order. @DharaParmar - I have no idea, was asked in an interview.

Comment: Why don't you try to make an algorithm for such kind of matching??

Comment: How would the algorithm determine which version is spelled correct?

Comment: Any way the answer I need is marked below, you can modify the question and make it narrower if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you say "unique" which implies *difference* but your example shows *intersection*.  If you need it the other way around use `array_udiff()` instead:

```
$result = array_uintersect($a, $b,  function($a, $b) {
                                        $a = str_split($a);
                                        $b = str_split($b);
                                        sort($a);
                                        sort($b);
                                        implode($a);
                                        implode($b);

                                        if($a == $b) {
                                            return 0;
                                        } elseif ($a > $b) {
                                            return 1;
                                        } else {
                                            return -1;
                                        }
                                    });
```

- split the strings into arrays
- sort the arrays
- implode back into strings
- compares the strings
- calling this through `array_uintersect()` returns elements in `$a` that are in `$b`

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => apple
    [1] => banana
)
```

Comment: Perfect.. The sorting does the trick, I didn't thought that much. Thankyou.